# A List of Google Prettify Language Codes

Tags: google-code-prettify

I cannot find this anywhere and I swear I used to be able to very simply without much prying. Can anyone help me? Thanks. I would appreciate it. Also, does **prettify** support Batch?

Comment: Slightly related and just as reference a question on [meta]: [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184108).

Comment: This reminder is partly for my own benefit:   . . . Specify code language ([tag:vb]/[tag:vba] as example):  `<!-- language: lang-vb -->` . . . Set language for entire post: `<!-- language-all: lang-vb -->`  Disable prettify: `<!-- language: lang-none -->`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can find a table in the [FAQ](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/blob/master/README.md), under the header [*For which languages does it work?*](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/blob/master/README.md#user-content-for-which-languages-does-it-work):

> The comments in prettify.js are authoritative but the lexer should work on a number of languages including C and friends, Java, Python, Bash, SQL, HTML, XML, CSS, Javascript, Makefiles, and Rust. It works passably on Ruby, PHP, VB, and Awk and a decent subset of Perl and Ruby, but, because of commenting conventions, but doesn't work on Smalltalk.
>
> Other languages are supported via extensions: ...

---

You can find the handlers, with their extensions in [the loader directory](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/tree/master/loader)

---

For the mapping from extensions to builtin languages, see the `registerLangHandler` calls in [prettify.js](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/blob/c67d80209c38e55431e6659ec51fc2d6a96ecf38/src/prettify.js#L1349-L1447)

Answer (score 23):

I thought it would be helpful to have an actual list rather than just a link. I found it in the [loader directory](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/tree/master/loader) that @MikeSamuel linked to from [Javascript code prettifier](https://github.com/google/code-prettify). As the readme states, the [prettify.js](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/blob/master/js-modules/prettify.js) comments are the authoritative source. However, [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work) provided a better formatted list, so I will copy that below. Refer to the the links for the most up-to-date information.

If you are using the Prettify codes to markup Stack Overflow code, you use

```
<!-- language: lang-or-tag-here -->

    your code
```

> ## [Language Codes:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/284743)
>
> Let Prettify interpret the code and guess.
>
> ```
> default
> ```
>
> Explicitly do not use any syntax highlighting.
>
> ```
> lang-none
> ```
>
> Bash and other Shell scripting
>
> ```
> lang-bash, lang-bsh, lang-csh, lang-sh
> ```
>
> C, C++, et al
>
> ```
> lang-c, lang-cc, lang-cpp, lang-cxx, lang-cyc, lang-m
> ```
>
> C#
>
> ```
> lang-cs
> ```
>
> Clojure
>
> ```
> lang-clj
> ```
>
> CoffeeScript
>
> ```
> lang-coffee
> ```
>
> CSS
>
> ```
> lang-css
> ```
>
> Dart
>
> ```
> lang-dart
> ```
>
> Delphi
>
> ```
> lang-pascal
> ```
>
> Erlang
>
> ```
> lang-erl, lang-erlang
> ```
>
> Go
>
> ```
> lang-go
> ```
>
> Haskell
>
> ```
> lang-hs
> ```
>
> HTML
>
> ```
> lang-html
> ```
>
> Java
>
> ```
> lang-java
> ```
>
> JavaScript
>
> ```
> lang-js, lang-javascript
> ```
>
> JSON
>
> ```
> lang-json
> ```
>
> LaTeX and TeX
>
> ```
> lang-latex, lang-tex
> ```
>
> Lisp and Scheme
>
> ```
> lang-cl, lang-el, lang-lisp, lang-lsp, lang-scm, lang-ss, lang-rkt
> ```
>
> Lua
>
> ```
> lang-lua
> ```
>
> OCaml, SML, F#, et al
>
> ```
> lang-fs, lang-ml
> ```
>
> Pascal
>
> ```
> lang-pascal
> ```
>
> Perl
>
> ```
> lang-pl, lang-perl
> ```
>
> PHP
>
> ```
> lang-php
> ```
>
> Protocol buffers
>
> ```
> lang-proto
> ```
>
> Python
>
> ```
> lang-py, lang-python, lang-cv
> ```
>
> R and S
>
> ```
> lang-r, lang-s
> ```
>
> Regex
>
> ```
> lang-regex
> ```
>
> Ruby
>
> ```
> lang-rb, lang-ruby
> ```
>
> Rust
>
> ```
> lang-rc, lang-rs, lang-rust
> ```
>
> Scala
>
> ```
> lang-scala
> ```
>
> SQL
>
> ```
> lang-sql
> ```
>
> VHDL
>
> ```
> lang-vhdl, lang-vhd
> ```
>
> Visual Basic
>
> ```
> lang-vb, lang-vbs
> ```
>
> XML
>
> ```
> lang-xml
> ```

Comment: so there's nothing for property files or config files?

Comment: What about *Makefile*?